# PHP Redirect header for form resubmit not working

Tags: php, html, forms

I've tried a few methods found on this site regarding the prevention of form resubmission. However, the redirection function doesn't trigger for some reason. 
May I know what i'm doing wrong and how i can fix it?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['bookingsubmit']))
{
    $error = '0';
    require_once("makebooking.php");
    $i_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $i_slotno = isset($_POST['slotinput']) ? $_POST['slotinput'] : '';
    $i_vehicleno = isset($_POST['vehiclenoinput']) ? $_POST['vehiclenoinput'] : '';
    $i_vehicletype = isset($_POST['vehtype']) ? $_POST['vehtype'] : '';
    $i_spacesreq = isset($_POST['spaceinput']) ? $_POST['spaceinput'] : '';
    $error = makebooking($i_username,$i_slotno,$i_vehicleno,$i_vehicletype,$i_spacesreq);
}
?>

<HTML XMLns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xHTML"> 
  <head> 
    <title>Make a booking</title> 
  </head> 
  <body>
<div id="makebookingsection">
    <form id="makebookingform" method="post" action="">
    <h4>Book a time</h4>
    <p>Name : <?php echo $_SESSION['username']?></p>
    <p>Enter Slot Number : <input type="number" name="slotinput"></p>
    <p>Vehicle No. : <input type="text" name="vehiclenoinput"></p>
    <p>Vehicle Type : <input type="radio" name="vehtype" value="Truck">Truck
    <input type="radio" name="vehtype" value="Trailer">Trailer</p>
    <p>Spaces Required : <input type="number" name="spaceinput"></p>
    <input name="bookingsubmit" type="submit" value="Book" />
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['bookingsubmit']))
    {
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
    ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you're using output buffering, you can't simply echo `header()` once you've started sending HTML content. Either wrap the whole thing with [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php) or move your `header()` call to before your HTML output.

Comment: Thank you. Moving it to after I processed the data worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to implement a **[Post/Redirect/Get (PRG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)** Pattern. For the **Redirect** part, you have to send the [**header**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) before any output is sent to the user agent. To avoid caching, use **[303](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4)** response code.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['bookingsubmit']))
{
    $error = '0';
    require_once("makebooking.php");
    $i_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $i_slotno = isset($_POST['slotinput']) ? $_POST['slotinput'] : '';
    $i_vehicleno = isset($_POST['vehiclenoinput']) ? $_POST['vehiclenoinput'] : '';
    $i_vehicletype = isset($_POST['vehtype']) ? $_POST['vehtype'] : '';
    $i_spacesreq = isset($_POST['spaceinput']) ? $_POST['spaceinput'] : '';
    $error = makebooking($i_username,$i_slotno,$i_vehicleno,$i_vehicletype,$i_spacesreq);
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], true, 303);
    exit;
}
else {
?>

<HTML XMLns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xHTML"> 
  <head> 
    <title>Make a booking</title> 
  </head> 
  <body>
<div id="makebookingsection">
    <form id="makebookingform" method="post" action="">
    <h4>Book a time</h4>
    <p>Name : <?php echo $_SESSION['username']?></p>
    <p>Enter Slot Number : <input type="number" name="slotinput"></p>
    <p>Vehicle No. : <input type="text" name="vehiclenoinput"></p>
    <p>Vehicle Type : <input type="radio" name="vehtype" value="Truck">Truck
    <input type="radio" name="vehtype" value="Trailer">Trailer</p>
    <p>Spaces Required : <input type="number" name="spaceinput"></p>
    <input name="bookingsubmit" type="submit" value="Book" />
    </form>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Was looking for an example of this for awhile now.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `header()` before you start rendering `HTML`, as your code seems that there is no meaning to use it in middle of `HTML`.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['bookingsubmit']))
{
    $error = '0';
    require_once("makebooking.php");
    $i_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $i_slotno = isset($_POST['slotinput']) ? $_POST['slotinput'] : '';
    $i_vehicleno = isset($_POST['vehiclenoinput']) ? $_POST['vehiclenoinput'] : '';
    $i_vehicletype = isset($_POST['vehtype']) ? $_POST['vehtype'] : '';
    $i_spacesreq = isset($_POST['spaceinput']) ? $_POST['spaceinput'] : '';
    $error = makebooking($i_username,$i_slotno,$i_vehicleno,$i_vehicletype,$i_spacesreq);
}

if(isset($_POST['bookingsubmit']))
{
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
?>

<HTML XMLns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xHTML"> 
  <head> 
    <title>Make a booking</title> 
  </head> 
  <body>
<div id="makebookingsection">
    <form id="makebookingform" method="post" action="">
    <h4>Book a time</h4>
    <p>Name : <?php echo $_SESSION['username']?></p>
    <p>Enter Slot Number : <input type="number" name="slotinput"></p>
    <p>Vehicle No. : <input type="text" name="vehiclenoinput"></p>
    <p>Vehicle Type : <input type="radio" name="vehtype" value="Truck">Truck
    <input type="radio" name="vehtype" value="Trailer">Trailer</p>
    <p>Spaces Required : <input type="number" name="spaceinput"></p>
    <input name="bookingsubmit" type="submit" value="Book" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've put HTML contentbefore the header.Headers should be used before returning any output.